# Add servlet to management port in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-boot

I'd like to know how to add a (third-party) servlet to the management port in Spring Boot? I know that I can easily add a servlet using e.g. this approach:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean myServlet() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new MyServlet(), "/myservlet");
}
```

But this servlet will be exposed to the external/application port (8080 by default) which is not what I want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your target is a `@Bean` of type `MvcEndpoint` (for HTTP support) or `Endpoint` (for JMX only). Spring MVC has some `Servlet` wrapping stuff that you can adapt (e.g. `ServletWrappingController`). You can look at how the Jolokia servlet is exposed for specific details: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/JolokiaMvcEndpoint.java.

Comment: This is really close to a link-only-answer.

Comment: And the link is invalid now.